# How to subscript a dictionary that is stored inside a dictionary in swift?

Tags: swift

```
let current_data: [String : Any] = ["table": "tasks", "data": ["title": title_of_task, "completed_by": date_of_task]]

if (!description_of_task.isEmpty){
 current_data["data"]["description"] = description_of_task
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Value of type 'Any?' has no subscripts
```

Comment: This is a very bad dictionary. If this is a known structure — the table is a string but the data is an array of some sort — then this should be a _struct_.

Comment: Are you getting this “dictionary” from JSON in a network call by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As matt notes, you need to redesign `current_data`. It is possible to do what you're describing, but the code is extremely ugly, complicated, and fragile because all interactions with `Any` are ugly, complicated, and fragile. It seems unlikely that you mean "Any" here. Would it be reasonable for the value to be a UIViewController, or a CBPeripheral, or an array of NSTimers? If it would be a problem to pass any of those types, you don't mean "literally any type." You almost *never* mean that, so you should almost never use Any.

To answer the question as asked, the code would be:

```
if (!description_of_task.isEmpty) {
    if var data = current_data["data"] as? [String: Any] {
        data["description"] = description_of_task
        current_data["data"] = data
    }
}
```

Yes, that's horrible, and if there are any mistakes, it will quietly do nothing without giving you any errors.

You could, however, redesign this data type using structs:

```
struct Task {
    var title: String
    var completedBy: String
    var description: String
}

struct Row {
    var table: String
    var data: Task
}
```

With that, the code is trivial:

```
var row = Row(table: "tasks",
              data: Task(title: "title_of_task",
                         completedBy: "date_of_task",
                         description: ""))

// ...

if !descriptionOfTask.isEmpty {
    row.data.description = descriptionOfTask
}
```